# How to generate same random numbers many time using Key n C#?

Tags: c#

I am working on a stenography project and I want to generate same series random numbers on both side for encoding and decoding using any key.

Comment: You will need to split the 2 questions into two separate threads

Answer (score 3):

The [`Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) class in c# has a [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes in an `int` value as a seed

```
Random rand1 = new Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF);
```

Comment: please bro explain a bit more

Comment: I am not sure what more there is to explain that is not detailed in the documentation within the provided links?